# Delphi, TVirtualStringTree, WM_SIZE events when resizing columns

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have a descendant of `TVirtualStringTree` class with my own autosizing columns procedure. To make it work whenever the size of the control is changed I have overriden the `Resize` procedure:

```
type
  TMyVirtualStringTree = class(TVirtualStringTree)
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;
.....
procedure TMyVirtualStringTree.Resize;
var
  cb: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if Header.Columns.Count > 0 then
    for cb := 0 to Header.Columns.Count - 1 do
      Header.Columns[cb].Width := round((Width - 20) / Header.Columns.Count);
end;
```

Everything works fine except one thing: resizing columns manually (by mouse on the header) without changing actual size of the control causes generation of unwanted `WM_SIZE` events with different LParams (control size). And thus `Resize` is called and columns automatically adjust their width which I didn't mean them to. How to make autosize work only when the control width is actually changed?

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to make the question clearer. I want the columns autochange their width only when the control itself actually resizes, not when one of its columns is resized manually.

Comment: I believe Molochnik wants to resize the columns on resizing of the entire component but prevent users from resizing them individualy.

Comment: Ok, example, that would be better. Say the tree width is 300 px, 3 autosized columns, each has the width of 100 px. I resize window, the tree become 600 px width. each column - 200 px. Perfect. Now I think that the 2nd column is too narrow and try to increase its size manually to make it of  300px width (so columns are of 200, 300 and 200 px width), of course horizontal scrollbar should appear cause all columns (700 px) do not fit control size (600 px). And this last part doesn't work - cause WM_SIZE is generated, resize is called and all columns are again of 200 px width.

Comment: All right, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Boolean flag `FColumnResize`, which you set to `True` in the `DoColumnResize` method.

In the `Resize` method check for the flag i.e:

```
type
  TVirtualStringTree = class(VirtualTrees.TVirtualStringTree)
  protected
    FColumnResize: Boolean;
    procedure Resize; override;
    procedure DoColumnResize(Column: TColumnIndex); override;
  end;

...

procedure TVirtualStringTree.DoColumnResize(Column: TColumnIndex);
begin
  inherited;
  FColumnResize := True;
end;

procedure TVirtualStringTree.Resize;
var
  cb: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if not FColumnResize then
  begin 
    Header.Columns.BeginUpdate; { Important: do not trigger OnColumnResize }
    try
      if Header.Columns.Count > 0 then
        for cb := 0 to Header.Columns.Count - 1 do
          Header.Columns[cb].Width := round((Width - 20) / Header.Columns.Count);
    finally
      Header.Columns.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
  FColumnResize := False;
end;
```

---

Another option instead of overriding `DoColumnResize` it is probably better to override and set `FColumnResize` to `True` in `DoHeaderMouseDown`, and back to `False` in `DoHeaderMouseUp`. in that case remove the `FColumnResize := False` in the `Resize` method.

Comment: It works fine, thanks, with just one flaw: right after the column widths are manually changed the first calling of Resize doesn't autosize columns cause FColumnResize=true. If there are a lot of WM_SIZE events (e.g. when you resize the tree by gradually resizing the form by mouse) it's not a big deal. But if it's only one WM_SIZE event (e.g. when you resize the tree by moving an outside splitter) the tree responds only after 2nd splitter move.

Comment: I see. I did not test this thoroughly. You can set `FColumnResize` to False in `DoHeaderMouseUp`. I think the idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks, but also in place DoColumnResize there should be used overriden DoHeaderMouseDown cause DoColumnResize is called when the columns are resized not only by mouse but programmatically as well.

Comment: Probably even better :) in that case remove the `FColumnResize := False` in the `Resize` method.